# can correctly shaded&reflecting transparent material be blended commutative?

Tags: opengl, transparency, blending

When rendering transparent materials order-independently, the 2 "easiest" options are addition (`GL_ONE,GL_ONE`; for example for sparks/flames/other light emitting particles) and multiplication (`GL_ZERO,GL_SRC_COLOR`; for example camera filters/etc).

Consider the scene of a house rendered from outside with some windows.
What you would usually do there when using those techniques would be:

1. render the opaque materials (skybox, walls, etc) with depth writing&testing
2. render the transparent materials (windows, etc) with depth testing and blending

the problem there is that when blending multiplicative it's impossible (as far as i know) to have light reflections on the glass, because that would require brightening (=src color >1.0).

when doing additive blending, you can render stuff like lights reflecting, but not filter the transmitted light (because that would require darkening (=src color <0.0)).

Now my first idea was to render the transparent materials twice, once multiplicative and with their transmissive color properties, and once additive and with their reflective color properties (and premultiplied lighting/etc). But then I would have reflections of farther away surfaces unfiltered by near surfaces.

So, is there any (efficient and not-so-hacky-looking) way to solve this problem that doesn't require multiple passes or sorting everything?

Comment: I fear you won't get around some kind of sorting transparent objects. If you have a KD tree or similar structure, this should still be sufficiently fast. And if you need per-channel filtering, you also need two passes. If a simple scalar filter suffices, you can utilize the alpha-channel (`GL_ONE, GL_SRC_ALPHA`).

Comment: well, my problem is i want realistic looking transparent objects, but don't know yet what my users will come up with in respect to "interlocking" objects/etc